# Header & footer Height with TCPDF

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

I have been looking everywhere but cannot find a reference to this.

Is it possible to have TCPDF automatically size the header and footer areas?

I am allowing users to create the header and footer themselves, but the height becomes an issue. I don't want to preset it too high or too low or the document will look poor.

Anybody have any ideas?

**How I currently set margins:**

```
//set margins
    $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
    $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting margins in the following way

```
$file->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
```

> TCPDF::SetMargins (       $left,
>         $top,
>         $right = -1,
>         $keepmargins = false 
>       )
>       Defines the left, top and right margins.

http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#ab3bbdb7c85ea08d175fd559be6132ba0

Comment: It is currently set to this. But if the header does not adjust the page "content" size... Thus the header and the top part of the content of the page overlap one another. please see my setmargins code above.

Comment: Adjust the link!

https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/TCPDF/classes-TCPDF/#method_setMargins